# How to open two html files with default browser

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a script that generates two reports and many many html files and I would like to open only two html files with the default browser.

My Powershell script finishes like this:

```
Invoke-Item C:\Reports\XUReport.htm
Invoke-Item C:\Reports\index.htm
```

My script is only opening the first file. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a little pause from one call and the other one:

```
Invoke-Item C:\Reports\XUReport.htm
start-sleep 1
Invoke-Item C:\Reports\index.htm
```